# how to verify what version of Log4j is used within a service

Tags: java, log4j

Say I have a lib `foo` that uses `Log4J` lib with version `V1`

This Library is used in a service called `bar` that also uses `Log4J` lib with Version `V2`

My Question is when we run the service `bar`, is it going to use Log4J V1 or V2 (or both)?

Comment: Both will be used

Comment: Well either or both *could* be used.  It actually depends on how the service + library *configure* the logging.

Comment: Solution: replace the log4j v2 JAR with the patched version ... whether or not it is currently used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Maven project then you can use [Maven Dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html):

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=*log4j*`

You'll see then in the output that some jars are `omitted for duplicate`.
How Maven decides what to use and what to omit in case of duplicates is not trivial, they don't call it dependency hell for nothing. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#transitive-dependencies